# RadioButtonList through Tabs

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik RadTab controls. I have taken three tabs.
In my application in RadioButtonList I have three radio buttons, if I click the `REPLACEMENt` radio button it will show next tab `ADTAF`

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" Skin="Inox" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1"
    SelectedIndex="0" Height="16px" Width="710px">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Purchase Details" Selected="True">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="CERF">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="ADTAF">
        </telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobtnlistcerf" runat="server" Width="300px" 
    Height="40px" onselectedindexchanged="radiobtnlistcerf_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>New addition</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Replacement</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Addition to main asset</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How to show next tab if I click on Replacement radio button?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but I think you mean that you want it to show 'CERF' next instead of 'ADTAF', in which case you would need to increment the selected tab index. If you wanted it to go through the tabs in order you could do something like:

```
RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = (RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex + 1)%(RadTabStrip1.Tabs.Count)
```

Maybe if you showed the code for  `radiobtnlistcerf_SelectedIndexChanged` it would be clearer why its not working